# Can you help me to make question 483886 more specific?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I did this question but they say it's too broad, I modified but I think they consider it still to broad. I don't understand why, can you help me?

[What is the approach to the mathematical modeling?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/483886/)

Comment: Kudos for asking for help on improving the question. Hopefully you get some good feedback!

Comment: I'd say that yours is a physics question that borders on philosophy, see for example [this](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/3916/is-there-a-known-limit-to-relationship-between-physics-and-mathematics), [this](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/10538/could-our-universe-simply-be-abstract-mathematical-existence) and [this](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/7137/are-electron-fields-physically-real) question on philosophy SE, and many more